# Selecting the top 1 of one column, for each value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

We have report cycles for our secondary school students. I am trying to write a query that will create a neat little table showing the most recent report cycle for each of our secondary school years.

I have found a way to show what I want, but it uses UNION and seems like there should be a much more efficient way of doing it.

So currently I am using this repeated 7 times, changing the WHERE clause so SchoolYear is changed to each of the ones we need it for (7 through to 13):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1
    CycleAllocations.ReportCycle,
    CycleAllocations.SchoolYear,
    CycleDetails.ReportName
FROM CycleAllocations
LEFT OUTER JOIN CycleDetails
ON CycleAllocations.ReportCycle = CycleDetails.ReportCycle 
WHERE SchoolYear = 7
ORDER BY intReportCycle DESC) AS CYCLE7
UNION
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1
    CycleAllocations.ReportCycle,
    CycleAllocations.SchoolYear,
    CycleDetails.ReportName
FROM CycleAllocations
LEFT OUTER JOIN CycleDetails
ON CycleAllocations.ReportCycle = CycleDetails.ReportCycle 
WHERE SchoolYear = 8
ORDER BY intReportCycle DESC) AS CYCLE8
UNION... etc etc
```

This produces a table like this:

| ReportCycle | SchoolYear | ReportName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 173 | 7 | Short Report March 2021 |
| 173 | 8 | Short Report March 2021 |
| 173 | 9 | Short Report March 2021 |
| 173 | 10 | Short Report March 2021 |
| 174 | 11 | Yr11 Mock Exams Jan 2021 |
| 172 | 12 | Long Report March 2021 |
| 175 | 13 | U6 Mock Exams Jan 2021 |

Is there a better way of writing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try, it may need tweaking as you haven't shared your table schema or any sample data.

Using a row number function to number the rows ordered so that your top1 row gets the number 1 and repeating that for each "partition" which is each school year, then only return the rows with a number 1.

I've used table aliases too which makes the query more terse and easier to read.

```
    select ReportCycle, SchoolYear, ReportName from (
        select ca.ReportCycle, ca.SchoolYear, cd.ReportName, Row_Number() over (partition by schoolyear order by intReportCycle desc )
        from CycleAllocations ca
        left join CycleDetails cd on ca.ReportCycle = cd.ReportCycle 
    )x
    where rn=1
order by SchoolYear
```

Comment: That's the one! Just had to add a WHERE clause in there to specify the 7 years I wanted and its come out perfect. Thanks buddy!